# determining most used set of words php mysql

Tags: mysql, string

I'm trying to figure out how to go about determining the most used words on a mysql dataset.

Not sure how to go about this or if there's a simpler approach. Read a couple posts where some suggests an algorithm.

Example:

From 24,500 records, find out the top 10 used words.

Comment: Are you analyzing data from a single field with multiple words?  A little more info would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, single field(column) with multiple word strings.

Comment: I have done something similar in a php script. Not sure I would try to do it in a single SQL statement. One problem is splitting the column up into words and returning each one as a row (I used a regular expression for this), but then defining what you care about as a break between words, and also how you want to deal with plurals (do you want to treat them as the same word or 2 different words). Might be easiest to write a MySQL function to split the column into words, returning multiple rows, then using that from within some SQL to do a count or the occurances.

Comment: Oh, should add that if they are just lists of words with a fixed delimiter then it is rather easier.

Comment: you're completely right, plurals should be taken as one word. I was thinking i take the strings and break these using space, there is no delimiter. so i guess one table will have the string sentences another the words found + it's counts which could be updated. thoughts? @Kickstart

Comment: If it is just split on spaces (so no commas, full stops, etc) then it is rather easier. I will have a play.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right, this runs like a dog and is limited to working with a single delimiter, but hopefully will give you an idea.

```
SELECT aWord, COUNT(*) AS WordOccuranceCount
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(SomeColumn, ' '), ' ', aCnt), ' ', -1) AS aWord
FROM SomeTable
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 + 1 AS aCnt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
WHERE (LENGTH(SomeColumn) + 1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeColumn, ' ', ''))) >= aCnt) Sub2
WHERE Sub2.aWord != ''
GROUP BY aWord
ORDER BY WordOccuranceCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This relies on having a table called integers with a single column called i with 10 rows with the values 0 to 9. It copes with up to ~1000 words but can easily be altered to cope with more (but will slow down even more).

Answer (score 4):

Why not do it all in PHP? Steps would be

1. Create a dictionary (word => count)
2. Read you data in PHP
3. Split it into words
4. Add each word to the dictionary (you might want to lowercase and trim them first)
5. If already in the dictionary, increment its count. If not already in the dictionary, set 1 as its value (count = 1)
6. Iterate your dictionary elements to find the highest 10 values

I wouldn't do it in SQL mainly because it'd end up more complex.

Comment: I suggest this approach ,You can add some filters as well for the commonly used words like "is, was , the, a" etc., Because if you taken the count blindly from the database you might end up with commonly used words in the top of the list.

Comment: If using a script is possible it has many advantages. Not only excluding common stop words, but also dealing with different delimiters, removing punctuation, turning plurals to singulars, and possibly dealing with synonyms and abbreviations. That said the common stop words could be removed relatively easily using a pure SQL solution (just have a table of stop words, do a left join to that table and exclude any row where there is a match).

Answer (score 1):

General idea would be to figure out how many delimiters (e.g. spaces) are in each field, and run `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in a loop, for each such field.  Populating this into a temporary table has the added benefit of being able to run this in chunks, in parallel, etc.  Shouldn't be too cumbersome to throw some SPs together to do this.

Comment: Hmm... looks like [someone else](http://www.montrealseocompany.com/2012/04/17/mysql-split-string-into-rows-function/) has already gone to the trouble of chaining this kind of thing together.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `COLUMNNAME`, COUNT(*) FROM `TABLENAME` GROUP BY `COLUMNNAME`
```

its very simple and worked... :)

Answer (score 0):

A little improve, remove stop words from the list with AND Sub2.aWord not in (list of stop words)

```
SELECT aWord, COUNT(*) AS WordOccuranceCount
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(txt_msg, ' '), ' ', aCnt), ' ', -1) AS aWord
FROM mensagens
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 + 1 AS aCnt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
WHERE (LENGTH(txt_msg) + 1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(txt_msg, ' ', ''))) >= aCnt) Sub2
WHERE Sub2.aWord != '' AND Sub2.aWord not in ('a','about','above', .....)
GROUP BY aWord
ORDER BY WordOccuranceCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```