# How to find most repeated word in a Column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of comments by users like:

```
id  Comments
1   The battery drains off very soon 
2   Screen Quality is very good
3   Even I have the same battery problem
4   Battery can be imporved
5   Screen goes blank sometimes...
6   Over all build is nice
```

So in the above case, I want to find the most talked about feature of a phone. So that result I can display as 50% people speaking about Battery, 30% about Screen and 20% Others.

How can achieve this? Also how to exclude preposition, conjunctions etc. from the result set.

Comment: This requires creating a hash and counting all the words. Does it have to be in mysql?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188667/determining-most-used-set-of-words-php-mysql for excluding prepositions etc, you have to make a list of words by yourself

Comment: No, Limitation like that, I was looking if MySQL has some Function for the same. I can do it via some JAVA language as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of keywords, you can do the following:

```
select kw.keyword, count(*) 
       from t cross join keywords kw on concat(', ', t.title, ',') like concat(', ', kw.keyword, ',')
```

As others have mentioned, though, you have a non-relational database design. The keywords in the title should be stored in separate rows, rather than as a comma separated list.

If your data is small (a few hundred thousand rows or less), you can put it into Excel, use the text-to-columns function, rearrange the keywords, and create a new, better table in the database.