# Counting most common word in SQL table with exclusions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to count the most common words from a table full of text (strings) in a MySQL database (using MYSQL workbench).  I got this code working  from reading another post (written by Kickstart).
This code uses a separate table called integer with 10 columns from 0 to 9 for counting.

Table Schema for the main table.  I'm mainly only interested in data the "Text" column.

```
'Id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', '0', ''
'PostId', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'Score', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'Text', 'varchar(4000)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'CreationDate', 'varchar(25)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'UserId', 'int(11)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'UserDisplayName', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT aWord, COUNT(*) AS WordOccuranceCount
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(Text, ' '), ' ', aCnt), ' ', -1) AS aWord
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 + 1 AS aCnt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
WHERE (LENGTH(Body) + 1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(Text, ' ', ''))) >= aCnt) Sub2
WHERE Sub2.aWord != ''
GROUP BY aWord
ORDER BY WordOccuranceCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It lists out the top 10 words, but they are full of short words like a, the, you, me... etc.
How can I change it to skip certain words like those?
How can I make it so that say, only words 5 characters and up are counted?

Schema of integers table
    'i', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''

Original post and code taken from this post.  I am new and couldn't post anything on it so I had to ask here.
[determining most used set of words php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188667/determining-most-used-set-of-words-php-mysql/14962990#14962990)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your table schema?

Comment: It would be better if you'd update your question with the table schema instead

Comment: Updated question with schema.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. How do I make it so that words that aren't found are still listed in the results as WordOccuranceCount as 0? Currently words that aren't found are not listed in the final results. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add another condition to your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT aWord, COUNT(*) AS WordOccuranceCount
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat(Text, ' '), ' ', aCnt), ' ', -1) AS aWord
FROM table
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.i*100 + 1 AS aCnt
FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
WHERE (LENGTH(Body) + 1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(Text, ' ', ''))) >= aCnt) Sub2
WHERE Sub2.aWord != '' AND
      LENGTH(Sub2.aWord) >= 5
GROUP BY aWord
ORDER BY WordOccuranceCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Just checking to see if the length of aWord is at least 5 chars, and if so, include it in the result set.  The LIMIT will be applied to the result set (post-filtering) and you should have what you need.

Comment: Thanks! it worked!  How can I modify it to only display the count of a list of words of my choice?  Like if I want to count how many times the word "security", or "ssl", etc, shows up?

Comment: @user3769475: No worries.  You can take out LENGTH(Sub2.aWord) >= 5 and put something like Sub2.aWord = 'ssl' or if more than one term, Sub2.aWord IN ('security', 'ssl', 'morestuff').  If you left LENGTH(Sub2.aWord) >= 5 in there, you wouldn't see ssl, though (because it's less than 5 chars long).

Comment: Does anyone know how I can modify this query to only count the words in rows with a certain time range?  I have a column called "CreationDate" that is a DATETIME (not a VarChar like schema above) which has this format 2011-01-01 00:46:21.  I would like to only include rows in the count from say, September 2011 or say Sep to Oct 2011.  I know you can use WHERE Year(CreationDate) = 2013 for example, but I don't know where to put it in the query to make it work.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3769475: Assuming the column is in table, try to put it after LENGTH(Sub2.aWord) >= 5; so LENGTH(Sub2.aWord) >= 5 AND ear(CreationDate) = 2013

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. How do I make it so that words that aren't found are still listed in the results as WordOccuranceCount as 0? Currently words that aren't found are not listed in the final results. Thanks for all the help! @VBlades